# Calling a Local Variable from Onclick Method

Tags: android

I want to Call all the Clues from this cluesDatasource.java to the Onclick Method.How can i Call Multiple Values from a Method. I need to Display Clue1,clue2,clue3 when the button Specific Clicked button is Clicked

cluesDatasource.java

```
public Cursor findCur()
{
   String idselect= "Select * From Entertainment Order By RANDOM() LIMIT 10";
   Cursor cur = database.rawQuery(idselect,null);
   return cur;
}
public String findClues(){
    Cursor cur=findCur();
     if (cur != null) {
        cur.moveToFirst();
        String Clue1= cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(cluesdbhelper.C1));
        String Clue2= cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(cluesdbhelper.C2));
        String Clue3= cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(cluesdbhelper.C3));
        String Clue4= cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(cluesdbhelper.C4));
        String Clue5= cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(cluesdbhelper.C5));
        String Clue6= cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(cluesdbhelper.C6));
        String Clue7= cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(cluesdbhelper.C7));
        String Clue8= cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(cluesdbhelper.C8));
        String Clue9= cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(cluesdbhelper.C9));
        String Clue10= cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(cluesdbhelper.C10));
        }
    return null;
 }
```

Onclick Method

```
clues.java 
if (v == c1) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));
        TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
        String Disp = datasource.findClues();
        text.setText(Disp);
        Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();
}
```

I Tried the Switch Case Method But it Retrieves the Clue from Different Rows .I need the 10 Clues from a Single Row .

Comment: First you should inform yourself about variable scope, because variable scooe is the reason none of your clues is accessible somewhere else than in the if statement. Also keep in mind to close your cursors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass some `int` value  `String Disp = datasource.findClues(position);` then use switch-case in findClues() method.

```
public String findClues(int position) {
    String Clue1 = null;
    Cursor cur = findCur();
    if (cur != null&&cur.moveToFirst()) {

        // here use switch case

        switch (position) {
        case 1:
            Clue1 = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(cluesdbhelper.C1));
            break;
        case 2:
            Clue1 = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(cluesdbhelper.C2));
            break;
        case 3:
            Clue1 = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(cluesdbhelper.C3));
            break;
        case 4:
            Clue1 = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(cluesdbhelper.C4));
            break;
        case 5:
            Clue1 = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(cluesdbhelper.C5));
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    cur.close()
    }
    return Clue1;
}
```

Comment: why -1 ? any proper reason ?

Comment: -1 Still leaves the cursor opened.

Comment: He asked how to get value and I suggest him. he didn't ask how to deal with cursor.

Comment: Your post shouldn't be the reason for his next post due to lacking quality.

Comment: Your code won't even compile.

Comment: I think for this reason you should edit my ans not -1.

Comment: I used your Method.It Works But it is Returning Clue from Different Rows.I Want all the Clues from a Single Row.

Comment: @Ketan You have 2000+ So one can expect your answers havi n g some quality. If you don't have the time to write answers with a minimum quality then don't answer until you have time. Since you edited your post I revoked the-1

Answer (score 0):

None of the string is returned from the findclues method. You are returning null always.

If I understand your question you are interested in sending clues one by one on the button clicked. For that keep a record of how many clues are served already using static variable and then keep showing more clues as more clicks happen for clues from UI.

If you want to return more than one value from the method easiest way is to return the list of  values. In your case it is string so you can return it like (one example you can use any other collection for the same)

```
public List<String> findclues() {
    List<String> clues = new ArrayList<String>();
    //method logic
    //for every clue call
    clues.add(clue);

    //cleanup
    //finally return arraylist
    return clues;
}
```

Comment: yes.I want to return all the clues.But I don't know how to return allthe variables.

Comment: You can return the array of all the string possible in the return, so your signature can be (one example you can use anu collection for the same) - public List<String> findClues() { ... }

Comment: I used switch Case Method.It Works But it is Returning Clue from Different Rows.I Want all the Clues from a Single Row

Comment: If you have any way to identify the rows in the database then you can change your query to get you the same row everytime.

Comment: I have a primary Key ID in the DB to identify the Rows

Comment: In that case I suggest you to get all the columns from the row in one go using List and change the logic in application to use List to read the clues until new clues are not required.

Comment: I can't get u .can u edit your answer ??

Comment: As there is no other unique way of fetching values other than primary key. I like to suggest you to get all the clues in one go once the clue button is pressed first time using arraylist logic mentioned in the answer above. Once you have all the clues available you can keep providing the clues on subsequent clicks from that array list rather than fetching it again from DB. In that way you have all the clues from the same row.